# Quick way to access an element of a two-dimensional vector safely with question mark operator

Tags: rust, vector

I have a two-dimensional vector (vector of vectors), and I want to access an element of it.
However, I cannot guarantee that the indexes of the element are valid (in the range of the vector).
In case they aren't, i want to just proceed with the program, without accessing these non-existent values.
I'd like to use the `?` operator to make the code cleaner.

Here's something that works as intended:

```
  if let Some(col) = data.get(outer_index) {
        if let Some(item) = col.get(inner_index) {
            println!("{:?}", item);
        }
    }
```

However, this is a lot of code to access this element. I wanted to employ the `?` operator, to propagate the `None` value, but the compiler complains:

```
if let Some(item) = data.get(outer_index)?.get(inner_index) {
        println!("{:?}", item);
    }
```

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a function that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `FromResidual`)
  --> ./src/test.rs:19:46
   |
8  | fn main() {
   | --------- this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`
...
19 |     if let Some(item) = data.get(outer_index)?.get(inner_index) {
   |                                              ^ cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `()`
   |
   = help: the trait `FromResidual<Option<Infallible>>` is not implemented for `()`
```

To my understanding, the `get()` method returns an `Option<Vec<>>`, and using the `?` operator would propagate the `None` option if needed.

How is my understanding wrong, and is there a way to do this without a ton of code?

Comment: The `?` operator doesn't "propagate" the `None` option, it **returns** it from the current function, which assumes that the current function returns an `Option`…

Comment: The duplicate applied to your question: `if let Some (item) = data.get (outer_index).and_then (|col| col.get (inner_index)) { … }`

Comment: Or: `if let Some (item) = (|| data.get (outer_index)?.get (inner_index))() { … }`